# Navigate to browser from selected listbox binded hyperlink (windows phone7)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox

I am bindind rss items from the net to this page, I cannot Seem to navigate to the link of a selected items hyper link which through binding is string.
 can anyone help me to navigate to weblink from a listbox item when selected ???

```
<ListBox Height="712" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listNews" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="468" SelectionChanged="listNews_SelectionChanged" Margin="0,-22,0,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                <Image Source="{Binding Avatar}" Height="73" Width="73" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,5,0"/>
                <StackPanel Width="370">   
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Newstitle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="28" />
                    <HyperlinkButton Name="{Binding NewsLink}" Content="{Binding NewsLink}" NavigateUri="{Binding NewsLink}" FontSize="18" ClickMode="Press" Click="Selected" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>


   private void listNews_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
        webBrowserTask.URL = **???????;**

        webBrowserTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting Target for your Hyperlink to "_blank".

Richard outlines the idea in more detail here.

[Problem opening web browser with HyperlinkButton](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/98fefb30-a9f9-4a5f-9942-6965cb2f2e3c)

Answer (score 0):

Look @ this question on MSDN Forums:

### [How can I make an External Hyperlink](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/4a6fca9c-2288-4ad8-907c-21ec64753bd5)

It uses `WebBrowserTask` to open browser and navigate to given url.

Comment: seems to just crash when i place a string binded to HyperlinkButton